# Report service doesn't generate the report

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportbuilder3.0

i have a problem with my reports, when i select a specific date on reprot builder, it's doesn't return values, but in others date it return normal values. In console of Google chrome, it's give me a "manifest.json" error.

has anyone had a similar problem?

On stored procedure, it's all normal. The problem apparently it is in report service or report builder

Comment: would help to include what the specfic date and how you filter your data etc

Comment: Sounds like your date field may also have time in it so it doesn't match a date. `WHERE CAST(DATETIME_FIELD as DATE) = @DATE`